# C - Getchar in a nested while loop causing infinite loop

Tags: c

I'm currently trying count the number of characters in a text file excluding line comments (like //comment), so I'm trying to identify the start of a comment (//) and use a while loop to read the comment until I encounter a EOF or new line character, thus I know that the comment has ended. The problem is that when I'm using a double while loop() to filter out line comments, it causes an infinite loop, because it will not exit the inner while loop. Here is my code. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? I'm stumped.

```
int numChars = 0;
int c = 0;
int prevc = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '/' && prevc == c) {
            while (c != '\n' || c != EOF) {
                c = getchar();
            }
        }

    numChars++;
    prevc = c;
}
```

For instance, if the text file were to contain //Hello, it should output 0 chars, while if the text file contains Hello it should output 5 chars.

Answer (score 2):

`c != '\n' || c != EOF` is always true.

It could only be false if both conditions were false, which would mean that both `c == '\n'` and `c == EOF` were true. Obviously, those two cannot both be true (unless `EOF` were the same as `'\n'`, which it isn't).

You need to use `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: I changed it to c != '\n' && c != EOF but for some reason, on an input of //Hello, numchars is still 1, but it should be 0 because I'm ignoring all comments. Would you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @wanderingstu: because you count the newline character. I think that's correct; the count should be 1. But I guess it depends on the precise requirements in the assignment.

Comment: but I think it should be 0 because in this case, I'm just typing out a comment with no newline character at the end. Is that correct?

Comment: @wanderingstu: How are you typing a comment without a newline at the end? Don't you hit the enter key at the end of the comment? If you put the input into a file, you almost certainly have a newline at the end (use `hd` to see the precise contents of the file.)

Comment: @wanderingstu If you do not want "comment with no newline character" to not count, do not let code proceed to `numChars++;
    prevc = c;` when an `EOF` is detected.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is always true.

```
while (c != '\n' || c != EOF)
```

Hence an infinite loop.